# Playing a sound file on start

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to play a sound file on start up of an application in Ionic as the splash screen loads. How can i do this? Couldn't find any documentation on it. The file is of wav type.

Comment: You want to play this sound at startup of app every time or in the first time that app start only?

Comment: I want to play sound only when the app starts first time, like when the splash screen is loading, not when if it is in background and user resume it.

Answer (score 0):

So my solution is below:

In app.js you can initialize a value in your localstorage

in this case: $window.localStorage['flag']

Also you must create a folder named audio in www folder and place there your wav file.

```
    .run(function($ionicPlatform,$state,$window,$q) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    $window.localStorage['flag'] = "false";

    flager = $window.localStorage['flag'];
    if (flager=="false"){
          var service = {
          loadMedia: loadMedia,
          getStatusMessage: getStatusMessage,
          getErrorMessage: getErrorMessage
          };

         function loadMedia(src, onError, onStatus, onStop){
           var defer = $q.defer();
           var mediaSuccess = function(){
           if(onStop){onStop();}
           };
         var mediaError = function(err){
         _logError(src, err);
         if(onError){onError(err);}
         };
        var mediaStatus = function(status){
        if(onStatus){onStatus(status);}
        };
      if($ionicPlatform.is('android')){src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;}
        defer.resolve(new $window.Media(src, mediaSuccess, mediaError,    mediaStatus));

    return defer.promise;
  }

    function _logError(src, err){
       console.error('media error', {
       code: err.code,
       message: getErrorMessage(err.code)
      });
    }

   function getStatusMessage(status){
    if(status === 0){return 'Media.MEDIA_NONE';}
    else if(status === 1){return 'Media.MEDIA_STARTING';}
    else if(status === 2){return 'Media.MEDIA_RUNNING';}
    else if(status === 3){return 'Media.MEDIA_PAUSED';}
    else if(status === 4){return 'Media.MEDIA_STOPPED';}
    else {return 'Unknown status <'+status+'>';}
  }

  function getErrorMessage(code){
   if(code === 1){return 'MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED';}
   else if(code === 2){return 'MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK';}
   else if(code === 3){return 'MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE';}
   else if(code === 4){return 'MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED';}
   else {return 'Unknown code <'+code+'>';}
  }

    return service;
      src = "audio/yoursound.wav";
     loadMedia(src).then(function(media){
     media.play();
   });
   $window.localStorage['flag']="true";
  }
 })
 })
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if solved your problem!